# container height is less than its content

Tags: html, css

I want the black solid border of class logo1 to be placed after pink but it is getting placed after blue which is the color of container. What changes i need to make?

```css
.menu-wrap {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 20px;
}
.menu {
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 700px;
  height: 75px;
}
.logo1 {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="logo1">
</div>
```

Comment: your question is very vague. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: do you want look like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/aoaheL3q/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT - - - - -**

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a069g74d/1/)

As requested, same result but edited the placement of the third div as required.

It's a little hacky with the positioning values, if you use a div instead of a UL for the menu and wrap it all in a containing div, you can position things much more tidily.

For now, here's how to get I working using the layout you've specified.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="logo1">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-wrap {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 20px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 700px;
  height: 75px;
}

.logo1 {
  width: 735px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 128px;
  left: 28px;
}
```

**OLD ANSWER - - - - -**

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a069g74d/)

I'm not quite sure what you mean, I hacked something together quickly to see if this is the goal you have in mind.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>
  <div class="logo1">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-wrap {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 20px;
}
.menu {
  background-color: pink;  
  width: 700px;
  height: 75px;
}
.logo1 {
  width: 737px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
  margin: -18px 0;
}
```

Comment: yes i want this only but i don't want to place logo1 div inside menu-wrap!

Comment: I've edited my answer.

You can use the position absolute value to move the bordered div to the exact position.

It's better to use a parent element with the 'relative' value to use as a reference point, but it will work without it.

Comment: thank you :) but how do you guess these 737px and  18 px values?

Comment: No guessing, you just edit them until they fit. Usually you could calculate quite easily by looking at each div's value, but the UL menu doesn't behave as tidily as a div does so it takes a little hacking.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.menu-wrap {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 30px 0 0 20px;
}
.menu {
  background-color: pink;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 700px;
  height: 75px;
}
.logo1 {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-wrap">
  <ul class="menu">
  </ul>
<div class="logo1">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have included logo1 inside menu-wrap but i don't want to place logo1 div inside menu-wrap..any other solution?